# Make button stay one color except when hovered over

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, focus

How can I make a button that changes color on `hover`, then returns to its original color after it's been clicked?

The problem is that my button starts with a red gradient, then changes color when hovered over, then turns white after it's clicked. But I want it to return to red after it's been clicked, not white.

I thought I'd found the solution by adding `focus`. This way, after the button was clicked, it returned to its original color while it was in focus. But then hovering doesn't change the button's color until focus is removed from the button.

I haven't found a combination of pseudo classes or javascript to keep this button red unless it's hovered over.

**Edit**

Per a comment by [@webeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2037924/webeno), I removed the CSS and tried a new approach using this javascript, but the button continues to work in its default style. (In this example the colors are blue, then red when hovered over.)

```
<button class = "btn">Go</button>        
<script>     
.red {background-color: #f00;
     }     

.blue {background-color: #00f;
      } 

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('red');
   }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).addClass('blue');
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have a look into a [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) pseudo class somewhere in your code, might be the culprit... ;)

Comment: ...or a `mouseout` / `hover` event in javascript...

Comment: Good ideas; I didn't have a 'visited' and tried to add one to see if it could set the button back to its original state, but that didn't work.

Comment: I also tried the `mouseout` javascript idea, but that didn't seem to work, either. I've updated my original post accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at my answer...

Comment: I've found that the white color the button became after being clicked is the default for buttons when used in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that for changing color on mouse hover, you just use CSS.

```
.btn, .btn:focus, .btn:active {background-color: #00f;}

.btn:hover {background-color: #f00;}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, aside from the slight typo reading `.button:focus` instead of `.btn:focus`. Thank you.

Comment: @SeamusMcBrown - you are already using "**btn**" class and the same html code snippet that's why I just give you css solution for your existing html.

Answer (score 0):

You added your CSS definitions inside the `script` tag, which obviously is incorrect. You should either have it in the `head` section under the `style` tag, or in a separate `.css` file and refer to it in the `head`.

So...

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

...or...

```
<head>
    <style>
        /* Your CSS rules come here */
    </style>
</head>
```

Once you do that, your code at the bottom of your question should work just fine (provided you link to jQuery properly also, just like you'd to your stylesheet, demonstrated above).

Here it is in full:

```
<head>       
  <style>     
    .red {background-color: #f00;}     
    .blue {background-color: #00f;} 
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.btn').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('red');
      }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).addClass('blue');
      });
    });
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <button class = "btn">Go</button>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6wbnvy7g/

One more thing though: mind you that you'd have to take care of removing the class each time an event is firing, otherwise you'll end up with both classes applied onto the element at the next time you're trying to hover over the button. So I'd change your jQuery code to one of the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      $(this).addClass('red');
   }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('red');
      $(this).addClass('blue');
   });
});
```

Or even simpler, using the `.hover` function of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').hover(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      $(this).addClass('red');
   }, function(){
      $(this).removeClass('red');
      $(this).addClass('blue');
   });
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle for that version: https://jsfiddle.net/6wbnvy7g/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and examples. The latter example works perfectly in JSFiddle, but in my code in Brackets. When I hover over the button, despite the CSS telling it otherwise, for some reason it changes to the default `button` gray color instead of red. Once clicked, it maintains that gray color until I move focus off the button, similar to the problem I was having before. This solution could definitely help somebody, but for me zatee29's is working best.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant it was working in JSFiddle, but _not_ in my code in Brackets. When I tried this solution in my code, the button still behaved like it did in my original problem, in that the button didn't return to its original color after being clicked.

Comment: all these things need to be very clear in your original question... think about those who see it the first time, they won't run around looking for clues in comments...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for my code is to follow zatee29's answer of placing this in the css:

```
.btn, .btn:focus, .btn:active {background-color: #00f;}
.btn:hover {background-color: #f00;}
```

with of course the button in the html:

```
<button class = "btn">Go</button>
```

The result works exactly as desired. The button starts blue, changes to red when hovered over, then returns to blue.

Note that webeno's second solution provides the same functionality in JSFiddle, though I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work in my existing program.

Comment: one doesn't answer on their own question the same as someone already answered... put your notes into the comments on your question or the accepted answer... if it's not complete, don't accept it as the correct one...

Comment: Zatee29's answer was nearly perfect, I just thought I could convey the final solution more clearly than in a comment. But yeah, if I'd thought about it, the answer section does look pretty odd this way...

Comment: it's simply not meant for it... if you need a more complete answer, ask the answerer to do it